# How to solve codes after for loop that do not execute in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, execute, resolve

I have this code under my **form_load**

```
    checkUser = False
    MsgBox("test start")
    result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ArrayList)(getJSon("https://dtitdtr.herokuapp.com/employees"))
    MsgBox("test after result before for-each")
    For Each value As Object In result
        token = JObject.Parse(value.ToString())
        id = token.SelectToken("id")
        fname = token.SelectToken("fname")
        mname = token.SelectToken("mname")
        lname = token.SelectToken("lname")
        contact = token.SelectToken("contactno")
        add = token.SelectToken("address")
        user = token.SelectToken("username")
        pass = token.SeelectToken("password")
        If user.ToString().ToUpper().Equals(GetUName()) Then
            checkUser = True
            Exit For
        Else
            checkUser = False
        End If
    Next value
    MsgBox("test after next value")
    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
```

and when I run the program, the first two(2) message boxes displayed and the last one, which is after the Next Value, won't display.

I don't quite get what's going on; since yerterday, when I run it, it went just fine and right now after adding codes for *update info*, which does not suppose to affect the form_load, **the codes right after for loop won't execute**. What is the problem with this?

I got something [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?663539-RESOLVED-Code-does-not-execute-after-For-Each-Next-Loop) that says *"an exception is being thrown"* but I don't even have a Try Catch in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that your code throws some `Exception` inside the `For`, so i suggest you to include `Try.. Catch` get the exception details. that helps you to detect the problem.

```
        Try
            For Each value As Object In result
                token = JObject.Parse(value.ToString())
                id = token.SelectToken("id")
                fname = token.SelectToken("fname")
                mname = token.SelectToken("mname")
                lname = token.SelectToken("lname")
                contact = token.SelectToken("contactno")
                add = token.SelectToken("address")
                user = token.SelectToken("username")
                pass = token.SeelectToken("password")
                If user.ToString().ToUpper().Equals(GetUName()) Then
                    checkUser = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    checkUser = False
                End If
            Next value
            MsgBox("test after next value")
            reader.Close()
            response.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Exception :" & ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of it sooner... I've got my problem solved, thanks to you! :) I happen to just misspelled the last "select" word in SelectToken. Please don't downvote my question. ^^